# How to number certain text on java?

Tags: java, parsing

I'm trying to create a program that outputs certain keywords and what line they are on. I want the output to resemble something like:

1, Keyword, Public

1 is supposed to be the line that the word is on but i cannot figure out how to do this for each subsequent line.

Comment: Well, increment a counter each time your loop reads the next line. You posted no caode, so you can only get vague answers.

Comment: Hi JavaMan, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post what code you have tried?

Comment: I am unsure how to go about the counter as I don't know what the condition is for a new line, I am very new to programming so apologies if this is poorly explained.

Comment: Google for "Java IO tutorial". And you'll find examples of code reading a file line by line.

Comment: Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try to figure out if your question is already asked and answered. For example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17636355/2158271) is easy to find.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. StackOverflow is the wrong place for vague questions like this. Add some more details, show research effort and show us your attempts. Then ask a specific question about your code and where you are stuck at. Invest some time in your question. Then you will also get high quality answers and up-votes back instead of down- and close-votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a counter for the line number as you go along starting from 1 and increment it every time you hit the newline char in the text. Or,

```
boolean hasNewLine(String str) {
  Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
  return regex.split(str).length > 0;
}
```

This will split the string in n parts, depending on the number of newline characters.

Or, If you're reading from a file, you can use this to count lines

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
int lines = 0;
while (reader.readLine() != null) lines++;
reader.close();
```

I hope this helps.